# React Navigation Error on npm install

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a new react native app with react navigation.

I did the following:

1.) create-react-native-app myAppName

2.) cd myAppName/

3.) npm install --save react-navigation

4.) Expecting successful installation of react-navigation but instead i get:

```
C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test>npm install --save react-navigation
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\jest.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\t
est\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\jest as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\
node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\rimraf.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React
\test\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\rimraf as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\tes
t\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\uuid.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\t
est\node_modules\uuid
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\uuid as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\
node_modules\uuid
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\semver.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React
\test\node_modules\semver
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\test\node_modules
\.bin\semver as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Maima\Documents\GitHub\React\tes
t\node_modules\semver
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

npm WARN react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.23 requires a peer of react@* but none is i
nstalled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.23 requires a peer of react-native@* but no
ne is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.74 requires a peer of react@* but none is ins
talled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.74 requires a peer of react-native@* but none
 is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-nati
ve@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.2 requires a peer of react@* but none is
 installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but
none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.23
added 8 packages, removed 973 packages and updated 20 packages in 259.667s
```

Please Help, Cant npm start my React Native App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant comment because I dont have the points, so heres a tentative answer with the info at the moment:

I had similar issue when running Expo on Windows. to solve I had to close XDE and reinstall.

if that's not enough, delete the "node_modules"  folder and run "npm install".

Answer (score 7):

It can be solved by running a `npm install` command again and reinstall the `npm install --save react-navigation` command.

Comment: This was really helpful, it worked for me, simple and easy!!!

Comment: Yes this works but it's really weird. Just keep trying and it will be done at certain times...

Comment: thanks this worked on react native cli

Answer (score 2):

They aren't errors, just warnings telling you that some peer dependencies that navigation relies on aren't installed. Based on your commands, you need to run `npm install` or `yarn install` to install all the packages. Creating the app with `create-react-native` app give you a list of packages but you have to actually install them with `npm install`. If something funky happens, do what @vbandrade suggested and hose your node_modules and `package.lock`, then do a fresh `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

The same error appeared when I tried to run `npm install --save react-navigation`. Turns out I needed to run `npm install` prior to `npm install --save react-navigation`.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the steps but got error with `npm install`. I am also using Expo (as mentioned by @vbandrade) and there are also problems with that. First of all, i think `react-navigation` is changing a lot. After trying a lot (before applying the solution in the accepted answer), i installed `react-navigation` and its dependencies multiple times and it worked at one time when i first ran;

`npm install react-navigation`

then

`npm install  @react-navigation/native`

(which doesn't  make too sense for me as that gets auto installed with react-navigation). Then i ran;

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

for installing dependencies and it worked. Honestly i didn't understood anything that how it worked. So for the sake of learning i installed the project and reinstalled it with expo and after that nothing worked. So i applied @vbandrade's answer but it was giving some more errors after i ran `npm install`.

To get rid of these errors, i found another solution (from stackoverflow). Here is that solution.First of all delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and close your editor or any other file where your project is open (because node doesn't install some packages if the project is open).

Then,

First run this command;

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then,

```
npm install
```

And then;

npm install react-navigation

And at last install the dependencies;

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Run your project;

If using expo;

```
expo start
```

Errors must be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your expo server, stop the server and continue **npm install --save react-navigation** . It worked for me.